# Convert Columns in dataframe using astype - error in python

Tags: python, types

trying to convert column format using astype to int64, but getting error as below

"ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '75.01'"

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import http.client
import json
import numpy as np

ticker="USDT-INR"

# get order book for a specific ticker
conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("api.buyucoin.com")
payload = ''
headers = {
'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}

conn.request("GET", "/ticker/v1.0/liveOrderBook?symbol="+ticker, payload, headers)
res = conn.getresponse()
data = res.read()

#print(data.decode("utf-8"))
USDTINROBBuy = pd.json_normalize(json.loads(data), ["data", "BUY"], meta=["status", 
"sub_status"])

USDTINROBBuy['type'] = "BUY"
USDTINROBBuy = USDTINROBBuy.drop(['status','sub_status','total'], axis = 1)
USDTINROBBuy = USDTINROBBuy.sort_index(ascending=True)
USDTINROBBuy = USDTINROBBuy.head()
USDTINROBBuy = USDTINROBBuy.astype({'price': np.int8})
```

please assist i have tried a lot of combinations around astype of what i have read.

thanks

Comment: Just do `astype(int)` instead.

Comment: Try `USDTINROBBuy['price'] = USDTINROBBuy['price'].astype(np.int8)`

Comment: same error Pavel. no respite

Comment: same error "Dont Accept"

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame([75.01], columns=['price'])
display(df)
df['price'] = df['price'].astype('int8')
display(df)
```

How about to use astype('int8')?